# Keep TextView text, size, visibility after rotation

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

So I have a really basic layout where at the top of the screen there is an EditText and a Button. When someone hits the button, the EditText input is saved to a text view, then the EditText is hidden as well as the button. Here's my code for that:

```
public void setName(View view){
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.getUserName);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setName);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayName);
    playerName = editText.getText().toString();
    textView.setText(playerName);
    editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Well when the screen is rotated, onCreate is called again, which looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_score_keeper);
        // Identifies a textView
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayName);
        // Hide that textView until later
        textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Set player name to default value
        playerName = "Player Name";
        // Set score to default value
        score = 0;

}
```

The problem with this is that it loses the fact that I hid the EditText and the Button, and also hides the TextView again.

How can I keep all of those properties the same? (eg keep the text the same, the text size, the visibility of a View, etc);
Is it possible to do with onSaveInstanceState?

Thanks guys.

OSFTW

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could definitely just do this on the Activity's savedInstanceState, but I'd also recommend (since this may be something you do in multiple locations) to just write a subclass of the View which also saves its visibility as state, for example:

```
public class VisibiitySaveTextView extends TextView {
    //These are just keys to save and restore values from the state
    private static final String SUPER_STATE = "super_state";
    private static final String VISIBILITY = "visibility";

    //Constructors

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState () {
        Bundle state = new Bundle();

        //Piggyback off of the View's implementation and store that
        //bundle of saved information in our container bundle
        state.putParcelable(SUPER_STATE, super.onSaveInstanceState());

        //Store the current visibility of the View in the saved state
        state.putInt(VISIBILITY, getVisibility());
        return state;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState (Parcelable state) {
        //state should always be an instance of Bundle since that's what
        //we're saving, but check for safety
        if (state instanceof Bundle) {
            Bundle savedState = (Bundle)state;

            //Set the visibility of the View to match the visibility that
            //we retained in onSavedInstanceState(), falling back to the 
            //current visibility as default if no state was saved
            setVisibility(savedState.getInt(VISIBILITY, getVisibility()));

            //Pull out the superclass state we saved, and let the superclass
            //handle restoring all of the other state
            Parcelable superState = savedState.getParcelable(SUPER_STATE);
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(superState);
        } else {
            //Nothing special to do here other than pass it up to the super
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Example for letting the Activity handle the state:

```
private static final String MY_EDIT_TEXT_VISIBILITY = "my_edit_text_visibility";
private static final String MY_TEXT_VIEW_VISIBILITY - "my_text_view_visibility";
private static final String MY_BUTTON_VISIBILITY - "my_button_visibility";

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    //Save the state of each of these. It's super important to add null checks here
    //(which is why I prefer to let the View handle it) as in some cases this can
    //get called after the Views have been destroyed.

    if (myEditText != null) {
        outState.putInt(MY_EDIT_TEXT_VISIBILITY, myEditText.getVisibility());
    }

    if (myTextView != null) {
        outState.putInt(MY_TEXT_VIEW_VISIBILITY, myTextView.getVisibility());
    }

    if (myButton != null) {
        outState.putInt(MY_BUTTON_VISIBILITY, myButton.getVisibility());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    //Check if we have saved state, and restore the visibility 
    //to all of the Views we care about
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        myEditText.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt(MY_EDIT_TEXT_VISIBILITY, myEditText.getVisibility()));
        myTextView.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt(MY_TEXT_VIEW_VISIBILITY, myTextView.getVisibility()));
        myButton.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt(MY_BUTTON_VISIBILITY, myButton.getVisibility()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I really appreciate it! I'm new to android programming, brand new. Could you add some comments to kind of explain what's going on so that I better understand it? Thanks in advance!

Also, there is a way to do this without creating the class? Because, if possible, I'd like to keep it more simple. If I could do it all in the activity class (idk if I can) that would be great!

Comment: Sure, I've added comments, and an example of how the Activity could handle it. I really don't prefer that method (although I certainly use it in places -- sometimes it's not worth subclassing if you're only using it once or twice); it seems much cleaner to let the View handle saving its own state.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it! I can see why it would be cleaner to let the View handle it, and also it just makes more sense. But for my case I think I should be able to let the activity handle it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Override:

```
   @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

            if (button not visible)
                 savedInstanceState.putBoolean("Visibility", false);
            savedInstanceState.putString("text", "EditView text");
    }
```

on onCreate:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {

boolean x = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("visibility");
    String s = savedInstanceState.getString("text");
// set values
}
```

Comment: Button visibility is a property of the view. For instance:
textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
So I don't see how I could use this to modify that property, unless I am misunderstanding.

Comment: if (x) textView.setVisibility(View.visible);